# TCP to Serial Port in linux for Matlab access

Tags: linux, matlab, tcp, serial-port

I have a CyberGlove that communicates over wifi by TCP.  I'm trying to redirect this to a virtual serial port so I can access the glove's transmissions in Matlab.  I've looked at socat, but I haven't been able to figure out how to simply redirect the data, and where I should redirect it to.  I've never worked with serial ports or TCP before.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use the TCP Port directly? Take a look at the TCP/UDP-Toolbox from from Peter Rydesäter: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/345-tcpudpip-toolbox-2-0-6

Comment: Well, that part of it seems to work, but now I can't get computer to get the incoming signal from the glove.

Comment: Could you be little bit more specific? What have you done, what is not working exactly? Do you receive any data from your glove (take a look with wireshark)?

Comment: I eventually got it worked out.  I just needed to play around with it a bit.  I had to do things in the exact right order for the glove to properly connect to the TCP socket.